# jQuery to Remove Class Surrounding HTML Elements Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onload

I have a `<div>` with a class of `fouc` that surrounds most of my main HTML elements. I have set this to `display: none` and would like to remove it as soon as the page finishes loading. However, this is not working as expected. Thank you for your help.

**CSS:**

```
.fouc {
     display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).on('load', function () {

    $('body').removeClass('fouc');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following snippet

```
 $(window).on('load', function () {

        $('.fouc').show();

    });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! Very simple and effective solution. Did not think of this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the element in your JS which has the class `fouc`. In your case you are selecting the `$('body')` - which means your are telling the browser to remove the `fouc` class from `body`, which actually didn't exist.

You can find and remove the class, just like:

```
$('body').find('.fouc').removeClass('fouc');
```

But this isn't a good practice to do.

Comment: @LordEwwLel It's my pleasure!